# 405 (Method Not Allowed) in live Shared hosting - Laravel and Vue3 with Vite

Tags: vuejs3, vite, laravel-9

So, this is my first post on stack, if I missed something please let me know.

So I have project that's working well on localhost Dev but when i uploaded to the server the API given 405 method not allowed.

I have a login form:

```
<form @submit.prevent="login" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="form.csrf">
          <p><input type="email" name="login" placeholder="Username or Email" v-model="form.email"></p>
          <p><input type="password" placeholder="Please Enter Password" v-model="form.password"></p>
          <p class="remember_me">
          </p>
          <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
        </form>
```

The form has some inputs, a textarea and a file input. Those are my routes:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::controller(AuthController::class)->group(function(){
    Route::post('/login', 'login');
});
```

When I submit the form I get the The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. error.

Here is my Route list :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krhkX.png)

after everything possible things updating still on same error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOKPk.png)

In Chrome network tab showing this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chwFE.png)

Maybe you guys have any idea what is happening here and point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: You should use POST as a method in Axios. Maybe you did not define it explicitly and Axios uses GET by default.

Comment: Hi Gabe,
i already have post method on axios request.

await axios.post('/api/login', form)
    .then(response => {}

and it's working fine on dev server

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. Can you look in to the Chrome network tab, select the failing request and look what it states in the Headers tab, under general?

Comment: @Gabe have a look this Image for header -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/chwFE.png

Comment: So you are sending a POST and the server recieves a GET. Then there probably is  a problem with a proxy, that forwards your POST as a GET. This might also explain the difference between dev and prod. Do you use a (reverse) proxy, like Nginx or something in production?

Comment: no, i'm not using any kind of proxy or nginx in production...

Comment: But you are uploading it to a hosting provider, don’t you? Maybe they can help you.

Comment: @Gabe ....finally resolved....it's issue of directory calls via htaccess....by the way Thanks

Comment: Ah, htaccess… always fun :-)